# How to change html hyperlink based on python output?

Tags: python, html

Hi I'm new to using html and python. But I need to use html and python interchangeably.

For example,

if python output = 30302,

then I need to put '30302' in the hyperlink.

[www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/)< output> = [www.google.com/30302](http://www.google.com/30302)

html = 'www.google.com/'

python = < output>

how would I combine those two?

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

I guess that you wanna create a new string from two parts, i.e. you have a string `"www.google.com/"` and a variable `output` with integer `30302` and you wanna get the `"www.google.com/30302"` (for the future, always provide full examples of your code).

So how can you do it?

## Convert `int` to `str` and concatenate `str`s

`result = "www.google.com/" + str(output)`

`str(x)` will turn `x` into a string

## Formatting

`"www.google.com/{}".format(31415)"` is equivalent to the `"www.google.com/31415"` string,
so `result = "www.google.com/{}".format(output)"` also will work

in python 3 we also have f-stings:

`f"www.google.com/{31415}" == "www.google.com/31415"`

`result = f"www.google.com/{output}"`

Comment: @Crystal if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.